# Is the YouTube JavaScript (iframe) player broken today?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Today, my iPad app, which uses the YouTube JavaScript iframe API, stopped working. On investigation, it appears that the player object is bollixed. For example, `player.getCurrentTime` is undefined (similar to other player members).

Another iPad app ([Jasmine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jasmine-youtube-client/id554937050?mt=8)) also appears to be incapable of playing YouTube videos.

It's Push Wednesday, which makes me suspect that something's been broken at the server end.

Comment: What is "Push Wednesday"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that this issue has been reported and acknowledged: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706